# How should I give a id to the button which displays each button in a for loop

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm creating a quiz application in Python Django where in the template I'm iterating through a list of questions and then iteration through a list of answers for the current question and displaying those. I have a button for each answer. When I click a answer button an ajax call is triggered which calls my view to check if the answer is correct and returns the response. As I'm iterating through the answers for-loop and displaying a button for each answer of a question how should I make the clicked answer button red or green depending on the answer I got from my view response telling me if it is right or wrong? I'm confused how to determine unique id for each button and then change the color of that button. Below is the code

```
<div class="row">
    {% for question in questions %}
    <div class="col-md-4" >
        <div class="card mb-2" id="question_counter" value="{{forloop.counter}}">
            <div class="card-body"  >
                <p>{{forloop.counter}}{{"."}}{{ question.question|safe }}</p>
                <br>
                 <div class="card-body" >
                    {% for answer in question.answers %}
                     <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary display: inline-block width: auto;" name="answer" id="submit" value="{{answer}}">{{ answer|safe }}</button></li>
                    </br>
                    {% endfor %}
                 </div>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Also I have attached  a sample showing how the html looks like.
Please let me know. Thanks

Not sure how to include an unique id for the answer buttons which are displayed using a for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that to get a unique id with django templates:

```
                {% for answer in question.answers %}
                 <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary display: inline-block width: auto;" name="answer" id="answer-id-{{answer.id}}" value="{{answer}}">{{ answer|safe }}</button></li>
                </br>
                {% endfor %}
```

You can bind it to classes also.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Add a class and id for each submit button in the answer and trigger jquery for class type when clicked.

```
<div class="row">
{% for question in questions %}
<div class="col-md-4" >
    <div class="card mb-2" id="question_counter" value="{{forloop.counter}}">
        <div class="card-body"  >
            <p>{{forloop.counter}}{{"."}}{{ question.question|safe }}</p>
            <br>
             <div class="card-body" >
                {% for answer in question.answers %}
                 <li><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary answer-button" name="answer" id="answer-{{answer.id}}" value="{{answer}}">{{ answer|safe }}</button></li>
                </br>
                {% endfor %}
             </div>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

write a jquery for handeling answer button click as

```
<script>
  $('.answer-button').on('click', function () {
    let answer_id = $(this).attr("id");
    let answer = document.getElementById(id).value();
    # parse answer to get answer id
    let id = parseInt(answer_id.split("-")[1]);
    # submit ajax code for checking answer
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{% url 'check-answer' %}",
        data: JSON.stringify({id: id, answer: answer}),
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            // handle error, change color to green, since you already got ID
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            // handle error, change color to red, since you already got ID
            console.log("Error: " + error);
        }
     });
  });
</script>
```